# Php support script with external user database integration

Tags: php, support-tracker

We are looking for a support desk software (web-based ticket system) that:

- Can use an external MySQL users table for its login...
- Preferably provides language files for translation/internationalization.
- Is simple and clean

I'll appreciate if you can suggest a solution.